# regex for ------/------ or 123456/123456 optional character

Tags: python, regex

The below regex works perfectly

```
[\s\S]*[0RECALL]?[\s\S]\d(?P<fpName>[R|U|J|L|I|N]\d\d\d\d),(?P<fpReceivedTimestamp>\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d,\d\d\d\d)Z,[^,]*,(?P<basic_weight>\d\d\d\d\d\d)\/(?P<payload>\d\d\d\d\d[\d]?),
```

for

```
0RECALL,J2516\n1J2516,04/20/16,1336Z,N103XA /CL30   ,123456/123456,
```

But I need a regex in which 
The last digits are optional  123456/123456 or  ------/------

so the text can be either

```
0RECALL,J2516\n1J2516,04/20/16,1336Z,N103XA /CL30   ,123456/123456,

or 

0RECALL,J2516\n1J2516,04/20/16,1336Z,N103XA /CL30   ,------/------,
```

What changes should I do to my regex . Presently I am Using the below online tool for help

[DEMO LINK](https://regex101.com/r/yUqoyU/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

| (pipe) is for OR.

I also replace some \d\d\d\d\d\d by [\d]{6}

```
[\s\S]*[0RECALL]?[\s\S]\d(?P<fpName>[R|U|J|L|I|N]\d\d\d\d),(?P<fpReceivedTimestamp>\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d,\d\d\d\d)Z,[^,]*,(?P<basic_weight>(\d\d\d\d\d\d)|[-]{6})\/(?P<payload>([\d]{5,6})|[-]{5,6}),
```

Edit:

- you can do (?P(foo)|(bar)) to match foo or bar in name
- You can use [\d]{n,m} to mach a number with n to m digits (m is optionnal)

Comment: Any explanation would be helpful ?

Comment: your solution works explanation would help me from avoiding any further mistake

Comment: OK i add some explanations

Comment: @HariomSingh There are still some (maybe) mistakes in the pattern. The `[0RECALL]?` matches a single char, `0`, `R`, etc. Not sure it is OK. `[R|U|J|L|I|N]` matches `|`, too as it is a literal char inside a character class. There is no point escaping `/` in a Python regex. It is a bad practice to put a single `\d`  into a character class, `[\d]` = `\d`. `[-]` = `-`. There is no need to use `[\s\S]` workaround in Python, use `.` and pass the `re.S` flag to match any char.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I understand there are lot of issues in the old legacy code ..I don't want to touch it now  ..it may change someones working flight plan

Answer (score 1):

You can change this part of the regex: `(?P<basic_weight>\d\d\d\d\d\d)\/(?P<payload>\d\d\d\d\d[\d]?),` to this:

```
 (?P<basic_weight>\d\d\d\d\d\d|?P<basic_weight>-{5})\/(?P<payload>\d\d\d\d\d[\d]|?P<basic_weight>-{5}),
```

Here, you are making the five digits optional using the `|` "pipe" operator.